# error occurs when comma separated affiliation in revtex4-1 if breqn is loaded

Tags: revtex, breqn

I encountered an error trying to use the breqn package.

First, the below snippet compiles fine without any problem.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,floatfix]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\title[]{Title}
\author{Name~GivenName}
\affiliation{Department}
\maketitle
ABC
\end{document}
```

However, if I add more contents to the affiliation (with comma), namely 
`\affiliation{Department}` to `\affiliation{Department, University}`. 
It does not compile now.
Why and how can I fix it?

I am using Texlive2013, updated up to date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `breqn` assigns a meaning to the active comma, which normally doesn't make any harm, because the comma is not active. However, the `revtex` class activates it and so the meaning given to the active comma becomes the one assigned by `breqn`, which is good only in math mode and is definitely different from what the class wants it to be.

You can reassign the correct meaning during processing of `\maketitle` (it shouldn't be needed afterwards).

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,floatfix]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\preto\maketitle{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`,
  \lowercase{\endgroup
  \let\saved@breqn@active@comma~% save breqn active comma
  \let~}\active@comma % set the active comma to what revtex4-1 wants
}
\appto\maketitle{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`,
  \lowercase{\endgroup
  \let~}\saved@breqn@active@comma % undo the change
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title[]{Title}
\author{Name~GivenName}
\affiliation{Department, University}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, just forget about the business with active comma and just issue

```
\makeatletter
\let\cat@comma@active\@empty
\makeatother
```

instead of that complicated code. The main purpose of the setting made by the `revtex` class is to make commas preferred line break points.